# Why does my gunicorn listen to my local Django development server on my live server

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

When I perform `gunicorn --log-file=- draft1.wsgi:application` to see the gunicorn log of my app, it says `Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000` which is the local Django development server. Can somebody tell me why it does this on my live django server? Here is the full log:

```
(env) james@postr:~/postr$ gunicorn --log-file=- draft1.wsgi:application
[2018-02-13 07:23:33 +0000] [25004] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2018-02-13 07:23:33 +0000] [25004] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (25004)
[2018-02-13 07:23:33 +0000] [25004] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-02-13 07:23:33 +0000] [25007] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 25007
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the localhost and means "this machine". It is not any specific machine.

Comment: Before seeing the above comment, I didn't understand OP's question... BTW, in your `etc/hosts` file, you can see `localhost` is pointing to `127.0.0.1`. In other words, the real `this machine` is `127.0.0.1`, and `localhost` is a built-in domain pointing to it. Sometimes a strange dns lookup strategy will make accessing `localhost` much slower than directly accessing `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

This is default and desired behavior as gunnicorn [deploy](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html) documentation clearly states

> We strongly recommend to use Gunicorn behind a proxy server.

So you should have nginx configured to proxy the following

---

If you still want to run gunnicorn on different ip/port combo you can use [bind](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#bind) setting

> `-b ADDRESS, --bind ADDRESS`